# HTML relative position and height problems.

Tags: css, html, position

I've made a image fader javascript which needs this HTML content:

```
<div id="finder" class="clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix">
    <figure> 
        <h1>Asd</h1>
        <h2>Asd</h2>
        <h3>Asd</h3>
        <img src="images/sample-image.jpg" /> 
    </figure>
    <figure> 
        <h1>Asd2</h1>
        <h2>Asd2</h2>
        <h3>Asd2</h3>
        <img src="images/sample-image-2.jpg" /> 
    </figure>
    <figure> 
        <h1>Asd3</h1>
        <h2>Asd3</h2>
        <h3>Asd3</h3>
        <img src="images/sample-image-3.jpg" /> 
    </figure>
    <p>some text</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#finder div {margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative;}
#finder figure {position: absolute; margin: 0;}
#finder figure img {width: 980px;}
#finder figure h1 {position: absolute;}
#finder figure h2 {position: absolute;}
#finder figure h3 {position: absolute;}
```

I'd like to auto-height the `#finder div` element based on the current `#finder div figure`'s height without javascript. Is it possible? The content is fluid, so the image is resizeable, thats the reason why i want to do this without javascript.

I solved the problem with a placeholder image which has the same height as the other images but I don't think its the elegant method :)

Thanks

Comment: I'll be happy to help you if you create a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

```
#finder,
#finder div { overflow: hidden; }
```

This way, the relevant divs will automatically get the height from the tallest element inside `#finder` and `#finder div`. jsFiddle with your JS code inside would much help.